# Jacoco Test Coverage always 0% on Linux; Windows works

Tags: linux, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, code-coverage, jacoco

i know that there are already a lot of questions about jacoco but i can't figure out a solution for my problem.

I'm using arch linux and it seems to be an issue with linux, that's why i hope that some of you may had the same issue before.

If i run

```
./gradlew connectedCheck
```

it always generates a test-report with 0% codecoverage. The generated report in the folder

```
app/build/reports/androidTests/connected
```

shows me that all tests have run without any problems.

A friend of mine ran the same tests on his windows machine and it generates a valid (not 0%) code-coverage report.

I can't find a solution because it seems to be caused by the operating system (Same tests work on a windows machine).

Can you please help me?

PS: i've run the test on two of my arch linux machines and both have the same problem: code coverage always at 0%.